# Cordova config.xml file getting re-written

Tags: cordova

I set up a basic Cordova project, and whenever I run cordova build, the config.xml file in IOS gets re-written to defaults, and any preferences I add in the config.xml in my project folder are simply appended to the config.xml in the IOS platform folder.  So, for example, by default the config.xml in the IOS folder has < preference name="DisableOverscroll" value="false" /> and when I add that same line (but with True) to the config.xml file in my project folder, the resulting config.xml in the IOS folder ends up having BOTH entries (false and true).  How do I get the config.xml file in the IOS folder to have the preferences the way I'm setting them???

Thanks!

Comment: You should not edit config.xml in IOS folder. It's modified at each build using the root config.xml values and modified by plugins. Instead, modify the /config.xml or /www/config.xml depending on version of cordova you used when creating the project.

Comment: @QuickFix - what you say makes sense... but I'm seeing the same as OP describes here, and it isn't about a platform-specific config.xml file (which I can't even find... maybe it no longer exists?): when I run `cordova build ios` my /config.xml gets rewritten with defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys. I think I found the answer last night. There's a
default.xml file in the platform folder. Once I modified the default
values for the preferences there, they consistently showed up
correctly in the config.xml whenever I ran the build command.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for. I can't believe this is not written in cordova documentation... It's misconception in the design of the build/prepare command of their cli imho.

Comment: There's no ```default.xml``` for us? Agree with @Żabojad this is terrible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 3.3.0, `config.xml` file for all build platforms are created at the project root folder instead of the `www` folder.

In your case, the second config located in `www` can be safely ignored, even if the parameter value is false.

Reference: [3 Cordova CLI Changes You Should Know About](http://devgirl.org/2014/02/10/3-cordova-cli-changes/)

--- Update: following QuickFix's comment ---

There are 3 places where `config.xml` can show up for iOS development.

1. Cordova project folder `MyApp/config.xml`
2. iOS xcode project folder `MyApp/platforms/iOS/MyApp_name/config.xml`
3. iOS www folder `MyApp/platforms/iOS/www/config.xml`

In my above comment, I meant the config in **No. 3** can be safely ignored. And the config.xml in **No. 2** is the actual file that is used by Xcode when you issue an IPA file.

The config in **No. 1** is only used by Cordova when you run the command `cordova build ios` or `cordova prepare ios` or `cordova run ios` - if you use these commands everytime you build an IPA then your primary config should be the file **No. 1** as @QuickFix mentioned, the configs at No. 2 and No. 3 is overwritten each time these cordova commands are run.

With my team, we run `cordova build ios` only once during the project's entire development life cycle. We make all the changes via Xcode and HTML files are copied directly to `MyApp/platforms/iOS/www/`.

*Note: For Android development, developers should always modify config **No. 1** only.*

Comment: The config.xml he refers is not the one that moved. The one that moved is www/config.xml which is now /config.xml for projects created with version 3.3.3 but www/config.xml still works for upgraded projects. The file Danny tries to update is the config.xml that resides in the ios platform folder. This one is overwritten with the one in root at each build.

Comment: @QuickFix you are right, I was referring to the config file located inside the `/platforms/iOS` folder. Sorry for the confusion, updated my answer to clarify this bit.