# Cordova 3 prepare is overwriting changes to config.xml and project .plist file

Tags: cordova

I have a combined Android and iOS Cordova 3.4 project, and I would like to know the proper way to set config.xml and project .plist file changes in the iOS project from getting overwritten by the cordova prepare command.

For example, I want to be able to use different package names and version numbers for the iOS and Android versions, I want to be able to set `DisallowOverscroll` to be `true` in the iOS version, but not in the Android version, set the background color for the iOS 7 status bar plugin to something other than black, target only >= iOS 6 in the iOS project's plist file, and a few other things.

All of these things are getting overwritten with their defaults every time I do a `cordova prepare`, and it's tiresome to keep manually overwriting these overwritten files between every prepare and build. I can wrap the scripts and put in custom build steps, but this just can't be right. It's reasonable to want custom values for each platform.

It's especially important that I be able to use different package ids, because these must match those which were already deployed before the upgrade from 2.x, when they were completely separate projects (making manually syncing the 90% of the code that is shared between them tedious and error-prone), to 3.x

There must be a correct way to specify different values for different platforms so they don't get overwritten. I saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978080/cordova-config-xml-file-getting-re-written?rq=1) on this, but it did not address how to have different values for different platforms, nor did it address the plist file, so any help in understanding what that right way is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It turns out this is a duplicate of a [question asked the day before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867075/cordova-how-to-set-platform-specific-config-xml-file-which-is-not-overwritten-a/22889496#22889496). I posted details of my workaround, including how to integrate it into the xcode build process with a pre-action.